# Keep getting 401 error from WordPress on AWS Lightsail

Tags: htaccess, wp-api

I'm trying to post to a WordPress server on an AWS Lightsail instance using node-wpapi.
However, the server returns a 401 error.

I already have a `.htaccess` file with `RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` to my `.htaccess` file and I already use 'application passwords' plugin.

How can I use node-wpapi to access the server?

My node-wpapi setting is here.

```
const wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'http://localhost/wp-json',
    username: 'user', //This is a default admin user.
    password: '*************************', //This is a password for application passwords plugin 
    auth: true,
});
```

My `.htaccess` file is here.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The error message is here.

```
 code: 'rest_cannot_create',
  message: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts.',
  data: { status: 401 }
```

My user profile page keeps displaying the following message.

`` > Due to a potential server misconfiguration, it seems that HTTP Basic Authorization may not work for the REST API on this site: `Authorization` headers are not being sent to WordPress by the webserver. You can learn more about this problem, and a possible solution, on our GitHub Wiki. ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

The WordPress made from AWS Lightsail instance image is bitnami WordPress.
And the bitnami WordPress is disabled Basic Authentication as default. So it needs some modification on `/opt/bitnami/apps/WordPress/conf/httpd-app.conf` to enable Basic Authentication. This modification is adding 3 lines below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

The httpd-app.conf ended up below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock|fcgi://wordpress-fpm" timeout=300>
    </Proxy>
</IfDefine>

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    
    

    <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
       <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://wordpress-fpm"
       </FilesMatch>
    </IfDefine>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
    
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/banner.conf"
</Directory>

Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf"
```

Then restart apache or the instance itself.
Then I installed the `Application Passwords` plugin and I use it as a normal procedure.
The following message of the plugin displayed on the profile page has gone.

```
 Due to a potential server misconfiguration, it seems that HTTP Basic Authorization may not work for the REST API on this site: `Authorization` headers are not being sent to WordPress by the webserver. You can learn more about this problem, and a possible solution, on our GitHub Wiki.
```

The HTTP_AUTHORIZATION environment variable in the .htaccess file doesn't need to be replaced REMOTE_USER.
Just in case, I show my .htaccess file below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This solution is from [this page](https://community.bitnami.com/t/wordpress-rest-api-basic-authentication-header-not-working/59090/6).
The difference of solution between this solution page and my solution above is I use the `Application Passwords` plugin but they use the [JSON Basic authentication plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth).

Comment: From the look of the server config you've posted, `.htaccess` files are completely disabled (`AllowOverride None`) - so anything you added to `.htaccess` is not doing anything. (?) The directives you have in the server config (ie. the WordPress front-controller) make the `.htaccess` directives redundant anyway. Incidentally, `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` is _the same_ as the directives you've ended up using, namely: `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)` / `RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]`

Comment: "the bitnami WordPress is disabled Basic Authentication as default" - It's not "Basic Authentication" that is disabled. By default, Apache prevents the `Authorization` header being passed to backend scripts as a "security" measure. If you just required Apache to manage the HTTP Basic Authentication then it would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
> ```

Unless you have specific requirements, you would ordinarily set the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment variable here, not `REMOTE_USER`, in order to essentially pass the `Authorization` HTTP request header as-is through to PHP/WordPress. (Which would seem to be what the error is suggesting?)

**UPDATE:** Also try setting `CGIPassAuth On` at the top of the `.htaccess` file. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66825530/369434) on the following [related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824195/missing-authorization-headers-with-apache).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried to replace `REMOTE_USER` with `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`, but it didn't work.
The reason why I use `REMOTE_USER` is that I followed the instruction on [this page](https://github.com/WordPress/application-passwords/wiki/Basic-Authorization-Header----Missing).
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Pierogi Also try adding the `CGIPassAuth On` directive. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Pierogi Not sure why they are suggesting to use `REMOTE_USER` with that plugin (unless this is something unique to that plugin, but it seems odd)? `REMOTE_USER` and the value of the `Authorization` header are two very different things. Normally, `REMOTE_USER` contains just the unhashed username (eg. `user`), whereas the `Authorization` header contains the authorization type and hashed username/password (eg. `Basic Z3Vlc3Q6YXNk`). This also contradicts [the standard WordPress `.htaccess` config](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/).

Comment: Thank you MrWhite! I've found a solution. It didn't need to replace `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` with `REMOTE_USER` as you mentioned. The problem was the `httpd-app.conf` file. Please see my solution for details.